# BarCodeScannerFragment Crop rectangle does not fit within image data exception

Tags: android

```
           java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
    Crop rectangle does not fit within image data.
      at com.google.zxing.PlanarYUVLuminanceSource.<init>(PlanarYUVLuminanceSource.java:50)
                                                                                           at com.welcu.android.zxingfragmentlib.camera.CameraManager.buildLuminanceSource(CameraManager.java:360)
                                                                                           at com.welcu.android.zxingfragmentlib.DecodeHandler.decode(DecodeHandler.java:77)
com.welcu.android.zxingfragmentlib.DecodeHandler.handleMessage(DecodeHandler.java:56)        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)                                               at com.welcu.android.zxingfragmentlib.DecodeThread.run(DecodeThread.java:101)
```

This is my `exception`  i'm using `BarCodeScannerFragment` `library`  to scan `QR code` .

```
class ScannerFragment : BarCodeScannerFragment() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        this.setmCallBack { lastResult ->
            Toast.makeText(activity!!, "Scan: " + lastResult.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    }}
```

This is my `Fragment` code I don't know why this issue is coming and how to fix it.

Comment: when you face this issue ? at the start or when you change orientation ? This issue is already logged in zxing library have you taken a look at that ?

Comment: when i run application its coming in library

Comment: https://github.com/mitoyarzun/zxingfragmentlib/issues/15  below is issue  but i am not able to find where i have change that piece of code where i have replace i am not able to find @Umair please suggest

Comment: this is the class and line mentioned :  PlanarYUVLuminanceSource 49 line
if you still can't find it then try to find the line of code in android studio you will get to it.

Comment: look its written there change rect calculate
int cameraWidth = cameraManager.getCameraResolution().y; int cameraHeight = cameraManager.getCameraResolution().x;
to
int cameraWidth = isVertical?cameraManager.getCameraResolution().y:cameraManager.getCameraResolution().x; int cameraHeight = isVertical?cameraManager.getCameraResolution().x:cameraManager.getCameraResolution().y;
it worked. :)  but int cameraWidth = cameraManager.getCameraResolution().y; int cameraHeight = cameraManager.getCameraResolution().x; not able to find

Comment: yes I know it's written there, have you tried to find it and replace the code as suggested ? I am sure you can because I can't help you find that line :) 
you have to do this part by yourself.

Comment: thats a reason i have posted this question i am not able to find code is not there where i have to replace  @Umair

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue.
Using zxing-android-embedded (https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded).

Zxing greater version 3.3.0 bring this issue to some users of my app.

Downgrading to 3.3.0 fix it.

```
dependencies {
implementation('com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0') 
{ transitive = false }
implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
}
```

This version is even compatible down to API level 14.